# Implement a random-number generator using only getpid() and gettimeofday()?

Tags: gcc, random

I am using gcc compiler to Implement a random-number generator using only getpid() and gettimeofday(). Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    int count;
    int i;
    int INPUT_MAX =10;
    int NO_OF_SAMPLES =10;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL); 
    printf("Enter Max: \n");
    scanf("%d", &INPUT_MAX);
    printf("Enter No. of samples needed: \n");
    scanf("%d", &NO_OF_SAMPLES);
    /*printf("%ld\n",tv.tv_usec);
    printf("PID  :%d\n", getpid());*/
    for (count = 0; count< NO_OF_SAMPLES; count++) {
    printf("%ld\n", (getpid() * tv.tv_usec) % INPUT_MAX + 1);
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
    {
        /* code */
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I gave a inner for loop for delay purpose but the result what i am getting is always same no. like this

```
./a.out 
Enter Max: 
10
Enter No. of samples needed: 
10
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Plz correct me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try separating out your calculations one line at a time with the printf statement, it might help you debug it.  Just a shot in the dark here, but it looks like you have all your variables as integers, try using some floats or doubles? also... shouldn't `gettimeofday(&tv, NULL); ` be inside the for-loop?

Answer (score 1):

`getpid()` is constant during the programs execution, so you get constant values, too.

But even if you use `gettimeofday()` inside the loop, this likely won't help:

1. gcc will likely optimize away your delay loop.
2. even it it's not optimized away, the delays will be very similar and your values won't be very random.

I'd suggest you look up "linear congruential generator", for a simple way to generate more random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Put gettimeofday in the loop. Look if getpid() is divisible by INPUT_MAX + 1 you will get the same answer always. Instead you can add getpid() (not make any sense though()) to tv.tv_usec.